# How to use querySelectorAll on a classnames generated by React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, css-selectors

I am trying to find a selector to select tweets from my feed. However, Twitter is using React and generates random class names like:

```
#react-root > div > div > div > main > div > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-aqfbo4.r-1niwhzg.r-16y2uox > div > div > div > div > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-1jgb5lz.r-1ye8kvj.r-6337vo.r-13qz1uu > div > section > div > div > div > div:nth-child(9) > div > div > article > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-18u37iz.r-thb0q2 > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-1iusvr4.r-46vdb2.r-5f2r5o.r-bcqeeo > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-19i43ro > div.css-901oao.r-hkyrab.r-1qd0xha.r-a023e6.r-16dba41.r-ad9z0x.r-bcqeeo.r-bnwqim.r-qvutc0 > span
```

[image]

I tried to find a pattern allowing me to retrieve the tweets. Is there a way to retrieve elements with generated by React ?

Comment: React isn't generating those classes.  A related css package might be doing it.  Either way, you aren't going to be able to write selectors for randomly generated class names.

Comment: Could you show `elements` which you want to select in `devTools`?

Comment: @jmargolisvt thanks for the reply. Its probably webpack doing this...

Comment: Surely there's a more... developer friendly way of obtaining tweets.

Comment: why not use conditional rendering?

Comment: @KevinB yeah, that’s true. My goal is to create a chrome extension, predict emotion of tweets and then inject an emoji in the browser. I already have the classifier in tensorflowJS and I thought about fetching tweets that way.

Comment: Please show whole `<span .../>` and its `css` style. You can select elements with other attr instead of classname.

Comment: @Antonio uhm. i see a whole span there in the image, I know an image isn't code, but... it's right there, with code in it, with the whole span, and many ancestor elements also with full attributes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this one.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".css-901oao.r-hkyrab.r-1qd0xha.r-a023e6.r-16dba41.r- 
    ad9z0x.r-bcqeeo.r-bnwqim.r-qvutc0 > .css-901oao.css-16my406.r-1qd0xha.r-ad9z0x.r- 
    bcqeeo.r-qvutc0")
```

if you wrote it:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".css-901oao.r-hkyrab.r-1qd0xha.r-a023e6.r-16dba41.r- 
    ad9z0x.r-bcqeeo.r-bnwqim.r-qvutc0")
```

this will give you the entire tweet block so you can retrieve username, tweet_id, and so on.
first query will only give you the tweet text.